# "IndexError: list index out of range" while fetching tweets using Tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm writing code to analyze social media patterns by various politicians. This one just gives a tweet count between datetimes. The following works perfectly unless I go too far back in time. For example, this goes back nearly a year:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Import libraries and modules

from api import api # Using Tweepy
import datetime
from   datetime import timedelta

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define variables

user          = 'vp'
timezoneShift = timedelta(hours=5) # Twitter times are UTC. Convert to Eastern Time. UTC−05:00 or UTC−04:00 depending on daylight savings. TODO: Fix for strictly EST or EDT?
startDate     = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0) + timezoneShift
endDate       = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 26, 0, 0, 0) + timezoneShift

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Fetch tweets

tweets = []
tmpTweets = api.user_timeline(user)
for tweet in tmpTweets:
    if tweet.created_at < endDate and tweet.created_at > startDate:
        tweets.append(tweet)

while (tmpTweets[-1].created_at > startDate): # If more to get, get more
    print('Fetched up to', tmpTweets[-1].created_at - timezoneShift, '...fetching more')
    tmpTweets = api.user_timeline(user, max_id = tmpTweets[-1].id-1) # ID minus one else we begin where we ended and get a duplicate
    for tweet in tmpTweets:
        if tweet.created_at < endDate and tweet.created_at > startDate:
            tweets.append(tweet)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Print tweets

count = 0
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.created_at - timezoneShift)
    count += 1

print('\n' + user, 'tweets from', startDate - timezoneShift, 'to', endDate - timezoneShift)
print('\nCount:', count, '\n')
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "count.py", line 22, in
>   
>       while (tmpTweets[-1].created_at > startDate): # If more to get, get more IndexError: list index out of range

But if I go back to, say, the first week of February, it works.

What's going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: maybe tmpTweets is an empty list?

Comment: Yep. I added print(len(tmpTweets)) to the end of the while loop, and it's 20 until it hits the final datetime. I still don't know why, though. I even changed the date range to the first week of January. So it's getting tweets from the original specified range. They're there, or at least they should be.

Comment: Aha! This error is occurring because the VP account didn't exist at the time I'm asking for it. It must have been made after midnight on inauguration day.

Comment: To be clear, there *are* tweets in the original specified date range, which is why it's confusing that I'm getting a list of zero. But I'm guessing that because I'm asking for tweets for a time before the account existed, that's causing the Twitter API to give me an empty list.

Answer (score -1):

The list tmpTweets cannot be accesed with the index -1 as far as i know. list indexes start at 0 in python so it makes no sense to pass in the index -1 and thus it is perfectly logical you are getting an index out of range error.

```
tmpTweets[-1]
```

is the issue

edit: sorry i was really really tired and it totally went over my head that a index of -1 is perfectly valid in python.

Comment: That's not true, [-1] means you're asking for the last item in the list

Comment: What Noa wrote is my understanding as well. Also, that doesn't explain why the script only fails when using old dates.